# What is the difference between “c'est pour cela” and “c'est pour ça”?

Tags: usage, pronoms, démonstratifs

Is it about the meaning of the sentence or the type of name that comes after it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ça" can replace "Cela" in all sentences, it means the same thing.
"Ça" is more used in familiar language and "Cela" in formal or literary language.

Answer (score -2):

*ça* is the contraction of *cela* just like *c'est* is the contraction of *cela est*.
However *ceci* and *cela* are differents like *this* and *that*.